# Border for div class in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to give **border** to a div **box** in javascript as i have give in 
css as border:2px solid #000;

How can i give it inside the for loop given below.

```js
elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor="#ff33ff";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor="#ff33ff";
    elements[i].style.border = "2px solid #000";
}
```

Try this. I hope it helps you.